# PowerShell Using multiple regex

Tags: regex, powershell

It seems to me that using multiple regexes in a function is not supported.. Or maybe I'm doing something wrong here.

I would like to validate input against the regex defined in `$NameSplit1` and `$NameSplit2`. I'm especially struggling with the differences in regex when the key `Special` for `Array2` is set to `$true`.

The logic would be to first check the `Country`, then if it's a `Special` color and then fill in `$True` or `$False` for the value `Valid` when it matches that specific regex format.

As always, thank you for your help guys.

```
Function Compare-Names {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]]$GroupName
    )
    BEGIN {
        $Array1 = "BEL","NLD"|%{[pscustomobject]@{Country=$_}}
        $Array2 = ("Red",$true),("Green",$false),("Blue",$True)|%{[pscustomobject]@{Color=$_[0];Special=$_[1]}}
        $Array3 = ("Fruit","Banana"),("Vegetables","Aubergine"),("Fruit","Appel"),("Vegetables","Carrot"),("Fruit","Peer")|%{[pscustomobject]@{Type=$_[0];Object=$_[1]}}
        [RegEx]$RegEx1 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)\s+(\w+)"
        [RegEx]$RegEx2 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)"
    }
    PROCESS {
        ForEach($Group in @($GroupName)){
            $NameSplit1 = $RegEx1.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            $NameSplit2 = $RegEx2.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            [PSCustomObject][ordered] @{
                'GroupName' = $Group
                'Valid' = If($Array1.Country -contains $NameSplit1[1]) {
                            if ($Array2 | where {$_.Color -eq $NameSplit2[2] -and $_.Special -eq $True}) {$True}
                            else {If($Array3.Type -contains $NameSplit1[3] -and $Array3.Object -contains $NameSplit1[4]){$true}else{$false}}
                } else {$false}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Correct formats:**

```
# When the color is not special:
"Country Color Something here" 
# Or when the color is special:
"Country Color-Type-Object Something here" # only when the Type-Object combination is a valid pair
```

**Examples:**

```
Write-Host "Valid" -ForegroundColor Green
"BEL Red Something extra here",
"BEL Red Something",
"BEL Green-Fruit-Banana Something",
"BEL Green-Fruit-Banana Something here" | Compare-Names
Write-Host "Not valid" -ForegroundColor Red
"GBR Red Wrong", # invalid country
"BEL Red-Fruit-Banana", # 'Red' has 'Special' set to '$True', so this concatenation isn't allowed (should have been 'BEL Red<space>Something'
"BEL Red-Fruit-Banana Wrong", # 'Red' has 'Special' set to '$True', so this concatenation isn't allowed
"BEL Green Something", # 'Green' is not a special color, so it needs a combination of Type & Object
"BEL Red", # No text after 'BEL Red' to be completely valid
"BEL Red ", # A single space after 'BEL Red' is not enough to be completely valid
"BEL Green-Fruit-Banana", # No text after 'BEL Green-Fruit-Banana' to be completely valid
"BEL Green-Fruit-Banana ", # A single space after 'BEL Green-Fruit-Banana' is not enough to be completely valid
"BEL Green-Fruit-Carrot Stuff", # Fruit+Carrot is an invalid combination
"BEL Purple Something", # Unknown color
" BEL Red Something"| Compare-Names # Beginning with a space
```

**Thanks to the guys below the full solution is:**

```
Function Compare-Names {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]]$GroupName
    )
    BEGIN {
        $Array1 = "BEL","NLD"|%{[pscustomobject]@{Country=$_}}
        $Array2 = ("Red",$true),("Green",$false),("Blue",$True)|%{[pscustomobject]@{Color=$_[0];Special=$_[1]}}
        $Array3 = ("Fruit","Banana"),("Vegetables","Aubergine"),("Fruit","Appel"),("Vegetables","Carrot"),("Fruit","Peer")|%{[pscustomobject]@{Type=$_[0];Object=$_[1]}}
        [RegEx]$RegEx1 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)"
        [RegEx]$RegEx2 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)\s+(\w+)"
        [RegEx]$RegEx3 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)"
    }
    PROCESS {
        ForEach($Group in @($GroupName)){
            $NameSplit1 = $RegEx1.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            $NameSplit2 = $RegEx2.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            $NameSplit3 = $RegEx3.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            [PSCustomObject][ordered] @{
            'GroupName' = $Group
            'Valid' = If($Array1.Country -contains $NameSplit1.Groups[1].value) {

                        if ($Array2 | where {$_.Special -eq $True -and (($_.Color -eq $NameSplit3.Groups[2].value) -or ($_.Color -eq $NameSplit2.Groups[2].value))}) {

                            If($Array2.Color -contains $NameSplit3.Groups[2].value){$true}else{$false}
                        }
                        else {If($Array3 | where {$_.Type -eq $NameSplit2.Groups[3].value -and $_.Object -eq $NameSplit2.Groups[4].value}){$true}else{$false}}
                      } 
                      else {$false}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mainly a problem with your regular expressions and the way you're trying to access captured groups, though the whole thing looks over-complicated. You should also provide sample inputs/outputs with your question.

The first scenario will never be met because you never examine it in your logic, you only look for the country in `$NameSplit1`, and `$NameSplit1` will only ever match the second scenario (`country color-type-object ...`)

The following should work for the second scenario:

```
Function Compare-Names {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]]$GroupName
    )
    BEGIN {
        $Array1 = "BEL","NLD"|%{[pscustomobject]@{Country=$_}}
        $Array2 = ("Red",$true),("Green",$false),("Blue",$True)|%{[pscustomobject]@{Color=$_[0];Special=$_[1]}}
        $Array3 = ("Fruit","Banana"),("Vegetables","Aubergine"),("Fruit","Appel"),("Vegetables","Carrot"),("Fruit","Peer")|%{[pscustomobject]@{Type=$_[0];Object=$_[1]}}
        [RegEx]$RegEx1 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)(\s+\w+)?$"
        [RegEx]$RegEx2 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)$"
    }
    PROCESS {
        ForEach($Group in @($GroupName)){
            $NameSplit1 = $RegEx1.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            $NameSplit2 = $RegEx2.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            [PSCustomObject][ordered] @{
                'GroupName' = $Group

                'Valid' = If($Array1.Country -contains $NameSplit1.Groups[1].value) {

                            if ($Array2 | where {$_.Color -eq $NameSplit2.Groups[2].value -and $_.Special -eq $True}) {$True}
                            else {If($Array3.Type -contains $NameSplit1.Groups[3].value -and $Array3.Object -contains $NameSplit1.Groups[4].value){$true}else{$false}}
                } else {
                $false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Given that:

```
[PS] > "NLD Red-Fruit-Appel" | Compare-Names

GroupName                                                                                                         Valid
---------                                                                                                         -----
NLD Red-Fruit-Appel                                                                                                True


[PS] > "NLD Red-Fruit-Grape" | Compare-Names

GroupName                                                                                                         Valid
---------                                                                                                         -----
NLD Red-Fruit-Grape                                                                                               False


[PS] > "NLD Red-Vegetables-Carrot" | Compare-Names

GroupName                                                                                                         Valid
---------                                                                                                         -----
NLD Red-Vegetables-Carrot                                                                                          True
```

Comment: Thank you arco444, I'm gonna play with it a bit because it's not exactly what I need. I'm sorry for not being clear enough, so I've updated the post with some examples on the desired result.

Comment: Almost there, I've added a third regex for the country `[RegEx]$RegEx3 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)"` to arrive in the scope as `$NameSplit1` stayed empty sometimes. Now all results are ok, except for one `BEL Red-Fruit-Banana Wrong`.. Changed regex to a little: `[RegEx]$RegEx1 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)\s+(\w+)" [RegEx]$RegEx2 = "^(\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)"`

Comment: Awesome, I found the solution thanks to you guys. Updated the post with the full solution too. Thanks again for the great help! I really appreciate it.

Comment: Shouted victory to early.. :P One issue left though `"BEL Green-Fruit-Carrot Stuff"` is saying `Valid=$True` while it isn't a known combination. Need to iron that one out first..

Comment: Found the complete solution now, updating the post again :)

Answer (score 1):

Now, it's early for me so bear with me. What I think you need is one RegEx with optional capturing groups. Then check against $Matches.Count and see if it's more than 3 to know if your Object/Type has to be validated or not. Probably want a switch for that. So my code compares against a RegEx that optionally checks for Object/Type. Then it runs a Switch check, and if there is more than 3 results from the RegEx match it checks for Object/Type and makes sure that the color is special. If it does not have more than 3 results it makes sure that the color is not special.

Actually, you weren't very specific on that, so I'm not sure how you wanted that to go. Is it:

A) IF it has Object/Type then it has to have a special color, but if there is no object/type then it doesn't matter if the color is special so long as it's a valid color?

Or

B) IF it has Object/Type then it has to have a special color, but if there is no object/type then it has to have a non-special color?

If it is A, then change the first `'Valid'=` line to:

```
'Valid' = If($Array1.Country -contains $NameSplit[1] -and $Array2.Color -contains $NameSplit[2]) {$True}else{$False}
```

The function that I came up with is:

```
Function Compare-Names {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True,ValueFromPipeline=$True)]
        [string[]]$GroupName
    )
    BEGIN {
        $Array1 = "BEL","NLD"|%{[pscustomobject]@{Country=$_}}
        $Array2 = ("Red",$true),("Green",$false),("Blue",$True)|%{[pscustomobject]@{Color=$_[0];Special=$_[1]}}
        $Array3 = ("Fruit","Banana"),("Vegetables","Aubergine"),("Fruit","Appel"),("Vegetables","Carrot"),("Fruit","Peer")|%{[pscustomobject]@{Type=$_[0];Object=$_[1]}}
        [RegEx]$RegEx = "^(\w+) (\w+)(?:-(\w+)-(\w+))?"
    }
    PROCESS {
        ForEach($Group in @($GroupName)){
            $NameSplit = $RegEx.Match($Group) | Select -ExpandProperty Groups
            Switch($Group){
            {($NameSplit|Where{$_.Success}).Count -lt 4}{[PSCustomObject][ordered] @{
                                                    'GroupName' = $Group
                                                    'Valid' = If($Array1.Country -contains $NameSplit[1] -and ($Array2 | where {$_.Color -eq $NameSplit[2] -and $_.Special -eq $false})) {$True}else{$False}
                                                    }
                                                }
            {($NameSplit|Where{$_.Success}).Count -gt 3}{[PSCustomObject][ordered] @{
                                                    'GroupName' = $Group
                                                    'Valid' = If($Array1.Country -contains $NameSplit[1] -and {$Array2 | where {$_.Color -eq $NameSplit[2] -and $_.Special -eq $true}|ForEach{$true}} -and $Array3.Type -contains $NameSplit[3] -and $Array3.Object -contains $NameSplit[4]) {$True}else{$False}
                                                    }
                                                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This produced the results:

```
GroupName                    Valid
---------                    -----
NLD Green                    True
BEL Red                      False
NLD Green-Fruit-Appel        True
NLD Red-Vegetables-Carrot    True
NLD Red-Fruit-Grape          False
NLD Red-Fruit-Appel          True
```

Comment: Thank you for your help TheMadTechnician, I've updated the post with some examples to be more clearas it's not really what I had in mind. My mistake, I'm sorry..

Comment: When I try to debug your function in the ISE it trows errors when moving into the `Switch`scope and then the ISE crashes. Very strange..